# How to move the ball in different directions?

Tags: c#, monogame, pong

Now when I hit spacebar it will go left or right, I want the ball to go straight first time.Then when the ball hit a wall, block or line after that I want the ball to go random directions with "-1" somehow. This is my first school game project, it's a one line pong game.

**Edit: Edit I've added "boll_speed.X = random.Next(-1, 1);", and that works perfectly!**

- linje = line
- liv = lives
- boll = ball
- poang = points
- I don't use "blockröd = blockred" right now
- blockgrön = blockgreen

  ```
  public class Game1 : Game
  {
  GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
  SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
  SpriteFont spritefont;
  Texture2D linje_texture;
  Texture2D boll_texture;
  Texture2D blockröd_texture;
  Texture2D blockgrön_texture;
  Texture2D gameover_texture;
  Rectangle linje_rect;
  Rectangle boll_rect;
  Rectangle blockröd_rect;
  Rectangle blockgrön_rect;
  Rectangle gameover_rect;

  Vector2 linje_speed;
  Vector2 boll_speed;

  Random random;

  int liv;
  int poang;
  int highscore;

  List<Rectangle> block = new List<Rectangle>();

  bool Start = false;

  public Game1()
  {
      graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
      Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

      graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 760; 
      graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 620;
  }

  protected override void Initialize()
  {
      linje_speed.X = 5f;
      boll_speed.X = boll_speed.X = random.Next(-1, 1);
      boll_speed.Y = 6f;
      liv = 3;
      poang = 0;

      random = new Random();

      base.Initialize();
  }

  protected override void LoadContent()
  {
      spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
      spritefont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Fonts/Myfont");
      linje_texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Pics/linje-lång");
      boll_texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Pics/boll");
      blockgrön_texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Pics/block-grön");
      blockröd_texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Pics/block-röd");
      gameover_texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Pics/GameOver");
      linje_rect = new Rectangle((Window.ClientBounds.Width - linje_texture.Width) / 2, 580, linje_texture.Width, linje_texture.Height);
      boll_rect = new Rectangle((Window.ClientBounds.Width - boll_texture.Width) / 2, 556, boll_texture.Width, boll_texture.Height);
      gameover_rect = new Rectangle((Window.ClientBounds.Width / 2) - (gameover_texture.Width / 2), (Window.ClientBounds.Height / 2) - gameover_texture.Height / 2, gameover_texture.Width, gameover_texture.Height);

      block.Add(blockgrön_rect);
      block.Add(blockröd_rect);
      for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
      {
          for (int g = 1; g < 13; g++)
          {
              block.Add(new Rectangle((g * 63) - 60, (i * 40), blockgrön_texture.Width, blockgrön_texture.Height));
          }
      }
  }

  protected override void UnloadContent()
  {
      // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
  }

  protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
  {
      if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
          Exit();
      if (Start == true) 
      {
          boll_rect.X += (int)boll_speed.X;
          boll_rect.Y += (int)boll_speed.Y;
      }

      if(Start == false)
      {
          boll_rect.X = linje_rect.X + ((linje_texture.Width / 2) - (boll_texture.Width / 2));
      }
      if (boll_rect.X > Window.ClientBounds.Width - boll_texture.Width || boll_rect.X < 0) 
          boll_speed.X *= -1;

      if (boll_rect.Y > Window.ClientBounds.Height - boll_texture.Height || boll_rect.Y < 0) 
          boll_speed.Y *= -1;

      if (boll_rect.Y > Window.ClientBounds.Height - boll_texture.Height) 
      {
          liv -= 1;
          Start = false;
          boll_rect.X = (Window.ClientBounds.Width - boll_texture.Width) / 2; 
          boll_rect.Y = 556; 
          linje_rect.X = (Window.ClientBounds.Width - linje_texture.Width) / 2;
          linje_rect.Y = 580; 
      }

      KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();
      if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) 
      {
          linje_rect.X -= (int)linje_speed.X;
      }
      else if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) 
      {
          linje_rect.X += (int)linje_speed.X;
      }
      else if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) 
      {
          Start = true;
      }

      if (linje_rect.X > Window.ClientBounds.Width - linje_texture.Width) 
          linje_rect.X = (Window.ClientBounds.Width - linje_texture.Width);

      if (linje_rect.X < 0) 
          linje_rect.X = 0;

      if (linje_rect.Intersects(boll_rect)) 
      {
          boll_speed.Y *= -1;
      }

      base.Update(gameTime);
  }

  protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
  {
      GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

      spriteBatch.Begin();
      if (liv > 0)
      {
          spriteBatch.Draw(linje_texture, linje_rect, Color.White);
          spriteBatch.Draw(boll_texture, boll_rect, Color.White);
          spriteBatch.DrawString(spritefont, "Liv kvar: " + liv, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
          spriteBatch.DrawString(spritefont, "Points: " + poang, new Vector2(350, 0), Color.White);
          spriteBatch.DrawString(spritefont, "Highscore: " + highscore, new Vector2(660, 0), Color.White);
          foreach (Rectangle g in block) 
          {
              spriteBatch.Draw(blockgrön_texture, g, Color.White);
          }
      }
      if (liv == 0)
      {
          spriteBatch.Draw(gameover_texture, gameover_rect, Color.White);
      }
      spriteBatch.End();

      base.Draw(gameTime);
  }
  }
  ```

**Having trouble with these parts:**

```
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();
        if (Start == true) 
        {
            boll_rect.X += (int)boll_speed.X;
            boll_rect.Y += (int)boll_speed.Y;
        }
```

---

```
        if (boll_rect.X > Window.ClientBounds.Width - boll_texture.Width || boll_rect.X < 0) 
            boll_speed.X *= -1;

        if (boll_rect.Y > Window.ClientBounds.Height - boll_texture.Height || boll_rect.Y < 0) 
            boll_speed.Y *= -1;
```

---

```
        else if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) 
        {
            Start = true;
        }
```

---

```
        if (linje_rect.Intersects(boll_rect)) 
        {
            boll_speed.Y *= -1;
            boll_speed.Y += random.Next(-100, 101) / 100.0f;
            boll_speed.X *= -1;
            boll_speed.X += random.Next(-100, 101) / 100.0f;
        }
```

Comment: So which part of this code are you having trouble with?

Comment: The ball in the pong game usually changes `y` speed (or `x` speed, I am not sure how your paddles are oriented) according to the place where it hits the paddle, and possibly the speed of the paddle. Also, it seems the same question has already been [answered on gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/4253/38920). The author of this answer has a homepage with a demo game at [richardcarter.org](http://richardcarter.org/).

Comment: I can copy all the code, so you understand more. Basically I want the ball to go straight the first time. When I press SPACE on start, but then it will go in different directions. Now it only goes up and down all the time. I will look in to that page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you mean you want the ball to change directions randomly when it hits the window boundaries or line. If so:

You're using constant values for your direction changes. Add a randomizer to multiply your boll_speed by.

For example, in pseudocode, instead of -1, do random(-1).

Comment: Okey, so I tried to do that, but a little confusing as you can see in my edited code up there. The game crashing when I try to click SPACE to release the ball now :P

Comment: @LuckeGG, when the SPACE button is pressed, you would still want constants for up and down. Going back to your original code:  `boll_speed.Y *= -1` is making your ball go up or down (on the Y axis). If it was going up, it'll go down. If it was going down, it'll go up. `boll_speed.X *= -1` makes your ball go left or right (on the X axis). When the ball bounces off the walls or paddle, you want to give it a value other than `-1` to make it go at an angle. Try that with your original code to see what happens. Then experiment with `random`.

Comment: Thank you, I did change it to `boll_speed.X = random.Next(-1, 1);` and that works perfectly. Did a little touch to yours and now it works! :)

Answer (score 2):

I will give you the generic idea. Please adapt it to your example

Lets say you want to move to all directions on the board, now imagine your board as a bi-dimensional array(all your pixels has an x,y representation on that board)

The (0,0) marks the left upper corner of your board, and your (width, height) mark the lower right corner. Your ball is on the middle of the board on the (x, y) position, where x > 0 and x < width(of the board) and y > 0 and y < height.

You have 8 different directions base on the picture below

[image]

Now it is time to translate those directions to a logical structure. You need to create an array for that, lets say we want to start from the NW direction. I will create an array with the numbers that you need to add to your (x, y) position in order to keep going in the direction you choose. If you see I am creating a bidimentional array

[image]

Now this is the pseudocode for your idea:

```
    int[,] directions = new int[,]{{-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,0}, {-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1}};

    public void Move(Game game)
    {
       Point currentPosition = GetYourCurrentPosition(); //the x, y
       int direction = GetYourRandomDirection() //this should be a random number between 0 and 7, beucase the array for directions has 8 positions. 


           int xDirection = directions[0, direction];
           int yDirection = directions[1, direction];

            //move inside the board forever
            while(true)
            {
               while(ICanMoveTo(currentPosition.X + xDirection, currentPosition.Y + yDirection)
               {
                 //keep moving on the same direction
                 currentPosition.X += xDirection;
                 currentPosition.Y += yDirection;
               } 

               //if you can't move anymore in the same direction, then change
               direction = GetYourRandomDirection();
               xDirection = directions[0, direction];
               yDirection = directions[1, direction];
             }
        }
```

Comment: Very smart idea there, but are there not an easier solution than this one. So the ball first moves straight up when pressing SPACE, then moving random directions after that? :)

Comment: yes, if you want to move to the N(straight up) then you need to set by default the direction to 1, then you press Space, int direction = 1 => (to get all the time -1,0 ) then you can move to the others

Answer (score 1):

`Random.Next(-1)` should give you out of bounds error.

You can use something like `Random.Next(-200, 0)/100.0f`, which will return a negative number between -2 and 0 (including -2, excluding 0).

But notice that this multiplication will lead to slowdown of ball over time. It might speed up to double of current speed, but it can slow down to nearly 0 in a single step. So I would rather first invert ball speed in y direction and keep it the same in x if you hit horizontal lines, and invert in x and keep in y if you hit vertical lines. Then do a random addition of a zero-means constant.

```
boll_speed.Y *= -1;
boll_speed.Y += random.Next(-100, 101)/100.0f; // Add random number between -1 and 1 with 0.01 precision.
// and nearly the same for X. Depending on the lines hit.
```

Comment: Hm, if you look at my code now. I have fixed some things like you said. But it was a little confusing, exact what I need to do. But it doesn't crash now, and the ball can get stuck on the left/right side. But the ball doens't go straight any time, just left and right.

Comment: @LuckeGG Sorry, I will try to be clearer next time :)
It doesn't go straight because you initialize speed in y with 6f instead of 0. Put speed in y to be 0 initially and it will start straight.

Comment: No problem, but when I set the X to "0f" instead of "6f" it will go straight up and down when I press SPACE. But it will go straight all the time now, even when it hits the upper roof? :)

Comment: @LuckeGG The thing is, you have 2 boundary conditions. You applied random to linje (pong paddles), but not to hitting the rectangle limits (table edges). You should put these `boll_speed.Y += random.Next(-100, 101) / 100.0f;` to rectangles too if you want to randomize there as well.